# Is it possible to include Runtime Directives in a .NET Core library?

Tags: c#, dnx

I am currently getting a MissingRuntimeArtifactException from a UWP app that is referencing a DNX library that I also wrote.  I have the following .rd.xml file included in the DNX xproj:

```
<Directives xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2013/01/metadata>
<Library Name="BinarySerializer">
<Type Name="BinarySerialization.BinarySerializer">
  <Method Name="Deserialize">
    <TypeParameter Name="type" Serialize="Required All" />
  </Method>
</Type>
```

If I convert the DNX xproj to a UWP library the runtime directive appears to be included and appears to resolve the exception in the UWP app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this is possible by embedding the .rd.xml as a resource with the project.json file.

```
  "resource": [
    "BinarySerializer.rd.xml"]
```